Using React-doc-viewer
I am using React-doc-viewer to render my docx file using
import { Document } from 'react-doc-viewer';
into the app but when i start my app this error is shown
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
i have checked but all my function and component are in correct place
and have search this issue on the web but not getting any clear answer on what seems to be the issue here
